# A quantity depending on two independent variables must be a constant, why?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, partial-derivative

I'm studying about Fourier analysis and there is one part in my book about partial differential equations I don't understand. It states that a quantity, which depends on two independent variables $x$ and $y$ must be a constant. Why is this?...I'm a bit confused about this statement.

I have included a screenshot of the part I'm having trouble with. I have highlighted the problem area with red rectangle. Green rectangle is used to highlight the definition of $L(u)$. This particular statement in the picture is confusing:

**"But since $x$ and $y$ are independent, a quantity that depends on $x$ alone and also on $y$ alone must be a constant"**

What does this mean? If I say that the size of my crops depends **alone** on the amount of water, I can't add to that, **and it depends alone on the number of sunny days**. If it depends alone on $x$ it means it doesn't depend on anything else but $x$, end of story right?

Hope I made myself clear what I'm asking :) This is just a bit confusing point in my book. My reference is Fourier analysis and its applications, Folland 1992 page 12.

[image: Source]

Comment: Fix $x$ and let $y$ vary. Since $P(x)=Q(y)$, it follows that $Q(y)$ is a constant $C$ (namely the fixed value $P(x)$). So now letting $x$ vary, we have $P(x)=C$ for all $x$.

Comment: This is a language problem, I think: in this context, "depends on $x$ *alone*" really means "does not depend on $y$". Same for "depends on $y$ alone" = "does not depend on $x$".

Comment: @nik +1 Thank you for your help =)